# Can we edit a row by updating sequence number of record 3 times while inserting those 3 into an array and insert to table?

Tags: db2, cobol

Suppose I fetch valid rows from table where `marks_colm = '300'` and we get 100 rows

For Each fetched row, I'd like to:

1. create 3 new rows:
2. increase max count of sequence_column by +1 set marks ='350'
3. again increase max count of sequence_column by +1 set marks ='351'
4. again increase max count of sequence_column by +1 set marks ='352'
5. copy these three rows to an array ..
6. insert the whole array into the table

Example
 input row:

```
Name1 ... RollNo31.... sequence5 ... marks300
```

output should be
 3 output rows for each one of the input row above

```
Name1 ... RollNo31.... sequence6 ... marks350
Name1 ... RollNo31.... sequence7 ... marks351
Name1 ... RollNo31.... sequence8 ... marks352
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve your goal using [multi-row insert](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-insert).  Note that, because there may be multiple errors encountered due to your inserting multiple rows, you must use the [get diagnostics statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-get-diagnostics) to retrieve details of any errors that may occur, [DSNTIAR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=dsntiar-) will be insufficient.